# How can i make a Site in IIS as Automatic delayed start in c#?

Tags: c#

I am configuring a website as follows:

```
        using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            
                Site website = iisManager.Sites.Add(name, location, port); //added site                
                website.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
                website.ServerAutoStart = true;
                iisManager.CommitChanges();
        }
```

How can i set it as Automatic Delayed start ?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you provide a link to the documentation for the class you're using as iisManager?  This might be useful to me in a project I'm working on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager?view=iis-dotnet

Comment: I have edited the question to include a full snippet

Comment: "Automatic (Delayed Start)" applies to Windows Services, not IIS Websites. IIS Application Pools _do_ have a `StartMode` property (that's either `OnDemand` or `AlwaysRunning`) and IIS Websites have a `Preload` property - but that's a different feature.

Comment: yes realised , have done it now